# Проблемы в интерфейсе программы Sql Server Managment Studio

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, ssms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все кнопки дублируются по несколько раз. Как бы работать возможно, но очень неудобно.
Кто-то сталкивался с таким, и как вы решали эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена! Удалил SSMS и установил с официальной страницы